# Alguém saberia me explicar pq apareceu isso"Exception has occurred: ImportError Missing optional dependency 'xlrd' "?

Tags: python, pandas

Estou utilizando o vscode para usar o pandas em python
Meu código

```
from IPython.display import display

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"Vendas.xlsx")

display(df)
```

e me apareceu esta informação na linha do "df = ..."

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
  File "C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Documents\Projetos c_py_lua\Projetos PY\Curso python\Intensivão Python 1\vendas.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(r"Vendas.xlsx")
```

alguém poderia me ajudar nessa do pq não estou conseguindo ler esse arquivo .xlsx?

Comment: Instale o *xlrd* que a mensagem some.

Comment: O pandas precisa que instale a dependência. Ou `pip install xlrd` ou `pip install openpyxl` dependendo da versão do pandas se não me engano.